# Visual Studio throwing spurious exceptions when running a program in debug

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm working on a VB.Net program in debug in Visual Studio 2010 (10.0.40219.1) (Windows XP 5.1 2600.xpsp-sp3-gdr.120821-1629), and have noticed that while debugging it runs very slowly. When run as an executable (even the debug executable) it bowls along at a splendid speed.

The cause appears to be that the development environment is generating large numbers of exceptions (appearing in the immediate window).

> A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException
>   occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

Does anyone know what the cause of this might be? It doesn't appear to have any adverse effect on the running of the program, other than to take a long time to get to the bit I'm trying to find the bug in. The exception doesn't appear to be related to any particular patch of code, and indeed it doesn't happen for most other projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to a similar question for you:
[A first chance exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020374/a-first-chance-exception)

I would pay specific attention to the suggestion by Marcus Andren:

> If you want to pinpoint where the exceptions are occurring, you can
>   select the Debug->Exceptions menu item, and in the dialog that
>   appears, check the first checkbox for "Common Language Runtime
>   Exceptions". This will make the debugger break as soon as an exception
>   occurs instead of only breaking on unhandled exceptions.
>
> This is also one reason why it is generally a bad idea to catch
>   generic exceptions unless you are clearly logging the information
>   caught.

Comment: Splendid, thanks. It zeroed in on the bad call straight away.