# Object variable or With block variable not set?

Tags: vb.net, exception

I get this error when i run my program:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
>
> Object variable or with block variable not set

Here is my code:

```
    Dim rt As String = ""
    Dim out As String
    Dim wRequest As WebRequest
    Dim wResponse As WebResponse
    Dim SR As StreamReader
    Dim time As Date

    time = Now()

    Try
        wRequest = WebRequest.Create(Address)
        wRequest.Timeout = 10000
        wResponse = wRequest.GetResponse
        SR = New StreamReader(wResponse.GetResponseStream)
        rt = SR.ReadToEnd
        SR.Close()
    Catch wex As WebException

        Dim status As WebExceptionStatus = wex.Status

        If status = WebExceptionStatus.Timeout Then
            MessageBox.Show("Could not establish a connection to the selected exchange server.", "Connection Timed Out", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        ElseIf status = WebExceptionStatus.ConnectFailure Then
            MessageBox.Show("Could not establish a connection to the selected exchange server.", "Connection Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        ElseIf status = WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError Then
            MessageBox.Show("Could not establish a connection to the selected exchange server.", "Connection Protocol Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)

        End If

    End Try
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: @antiduh I'm kind of new to VB.net how might i do that in VS 2012? Set a break point somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

The source of your error could be your `Address` variable.
Please try prefix with `http://` in front.

Example:

```
Address = "http://www.google.com"
```

for more further information, please read MSDN [WebRequest.Create Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw00b1dc.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I am checking your code and it works fine.

Here's a [demo](http://ideone.com/FkagAZ) although I made a little change on the declaration of `time` variable and putting a string on `WebRequest.Create()` like:

```
Dim time As Date = Now
```

and

```
WebRequest.Create("https://www.google.fm")
```

And as per my own search there is nothing much to be concerned about with this kind of error, see the link below.

[A first chance exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020374/a-first-chance-exception)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that `wResponse.GetResponseStream` is failing because `wResponse` is null. (which is probably because your Address variable isn't valid).

Try adding

```
Catch ex As Exception

    MessageBox.Show("Some other error occurred: " + ex.Message, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)

End Try
```

after your WebException Catch block to see what the problem is.

Or just put a breakpoint on `SR = New StreamReader(wResponse.GetResponseStream)` and look at wResponse (your choice).

Comment: The way i set up the function i pass the address variable to the function with a button like this 'textbox1.text = getData("http://somesite.com")'

Comment: I'm not sure how that relates to your `null ref` exception. If the site can be entered by the user, you should always code for the case where an invalid address is entered and handle it.