# A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, exception

I am writing a code to copy files from one directory to another. I am picking the file path from a 2D array.

```
for (int row = 1; row <= numRows; ++row)
{
      path = valueArray[row, 13].ToString();

      fileName = valueArray[row, 4].ToString();

      CopyDirectory.myCopy(path, "C:\\TestCopyDest", fileName);
}
```

The above program copies the first directory well. However, it then generates an exception:
`A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`.

What should I do? Do I need to create different threads for copying?

Comment: Is this doing something really clever? Just wondering why you invented a class to do this stuff, when it seems to be only a couple of lines of code using the Directory, Path and File Classes.

Comment: I am working on a project. And these lines of code are being used at many places.

Comment: Make's sense, though I'd have probably passed a collection of names and done it in a oner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [First Chance Exception](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidklinems/archive/2005/07/12/438061.aspx) doesn't mean your code has a problem.

Read the above link.

Comment: Thanks for the link. But it is working for only first path and failing for the rest of the paths?

Comment: The program terminates after copying first directory, indicating this exception.

Comment: Yeeees, but what is the exception's message?

Answer (score 2):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2021164/2409701) will help you

First chance means the program hasn't been able to deal with it yet, the debugger comes first. When you let it through, the app will deal with it nicely, so you don't get errors.
You should set up Visual Studio to ignore thrown (1st chance) exceptions, and only break on unhandled ones.

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the action line and write out the contents of your strings to make sure you're getting valid paths and don't have dupe file names:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("path: " + path + ", file: " + fileName);
//CopyDirectory.myCopy(path, "C:\\TestCopyDest", fileName);
```

Did you mean to copy everything into 1 target folder?

Answer (score -1):

Your program is running as a 64-bit process. Your DLL contains 32-bit unmanaged code.